# Move maven module between parent projects in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm having a maven multi module structure as shown below

```
ParentApp1
   - childApp1
   - childApp2
   - childApp3
TestParent
   - tchild1
   - tchild2
   - tchild3
```

After importing maven projects to eclipse it imports properly and individual projects are created for child projects. I want to move tchild1 module under ParentApp1 parent in the above strucute. After drag and drop the dependencies are not resolved. Even i tried with update Maven project in eclipse. Can anybody tell me is it possible to move modules between projects by drag and drop ? If yes, please provide me an any suggestion or reference else please tell me the steps to move the modules between maven projects

Comment: Im not sure about Drag and drop .so childApp1 need tchild1 dependency right? or you want to move tchild1 inside ParentApp1?

Comment: Did the parent POM reference change when you moved the child from one parent to the other?

Comment: do you have Pom.xml in ParentApp1 right just add the module under <modules>    <module>../tchild1</module></modules> tchild1 module should be same parentapp1 location

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the project on the pom.xml of the parent(ParentApp1) And also change the parent on the tchild1 pom.xml

ParentApp1 pom.xml
    `<modules>`
        `<module>tchild1</module>`
    `</modules>`

TChild1 pom.xml
    `<parent>`
        `<artifactId>ParentApp1</artifactId>`
        `<groupId>...</groupId>`
        `<version>...</version>`
    `</parent>`

Comment: I tried & when i am trying to build, it throws Child module C:\Users\xxxx\test_workspace\Parentapp1/tchild1 of C:\Users\xxxxtest_workspace\Parentapp1\pom.xml does not exist. In Actual project structure parent modules contains modules. But after changing in pom the parentapp1 doesn't contain tchild1 module.

Comment: Also you need to copy the tchild1 module inside the Parentapp1. This is the ParentApp1:
   - childApp1
   - childApp2
   - childApp3t
   - tchild1. And run maven update proyect